# "When you ......... your homework, you can go out"

Tags: word-choice

The options for this question are

1. finished
2. have finished
3. will finish
4. had finished

I chose the option 1 but the book says it is wrong.  Why can't we use "finished" here?

If we use doesn't it make any sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following options sound natural to my (American) ear:

- When you finish your homework, you can go out.
- When you have finished your homework, you can go out.

Thus, "have finished" is the best choice on the test question.

This sentence describes a situation that will occur in the future.  At that time, you will have finished your homework.  You will then be allowed to go out.

Starting the sentence with "When you finished" or "When you had finished" would describe a situation in the past -- not in the present nor in the future.  "You could go out" or "you could have gone out" would be appropriate for describing a situation in the past.